# How to create a development and a production builds in NetBeans?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, netbeans

I have developed a Tomcat application in Netbeans. Is there a way to have different builds for different environments?

For example, to use an application.yml different for Debug or Release build. When building in Debug build, an application.yml file containing configuration for debug is used while when building in Release build, an application.yml file containing configuration for production server is used instead.

If you know Visual Studio, I mean the same feature it has. In that IDE, I can in fact have a separate configuration file for each kind of build.

Thanks

Jaime

Comment: If you are using Maven then have a look at profiles: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html